# how to Manage Child activity within Tab Acivity when orientation changes?

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

I'm using tab widget.
When my child activity is running and I change the orientation,child activity destroy.

As a solution of this problem,I added
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` in all activity tags in my manifest.xml file.

I found that my app doesn't take xml file from `layout_land` folder.

Can anyone give me solution for this query?

Thanks in advance.

I found that using `onConfigurationChanged` method i can know the orientation and i have to set landscape file in layout folder instead of `layout_land` folder.

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.login_landscape);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.login);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your Activity is not destroyed since you have put `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in manifest so the `setContentView` is not called when orientation changes and therefore it doesn't pick the `layout` from the `layout_land`

**Update :** And this is not a problem with your `Tab-Activity` try it in normal `activity` it will not pick the correct `layout` or in general speaking no `layout` is picked your `portrait layout` is only rotated to be displayed in `landscape`